# XSL-FO 文字字間を制御したい

Tags: xsl, xsl-fo

XSL-FOで文字字間の制御を行いたいのですが、方法を教えて下さい。

例：文字字間広げ
すばしっこい茶色の狐は
↓
す ば し っ こ い 茶 色 の 狐 は

- 文字字間を広げる方法
- 文字字間を狭める方法
- 文字字間を一定の（Blockなどの）幅に併せて、広げる／狭めるをする方法

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 文字字間を広げる方法
>   文字字間を狭める方法

文字間隔は、letter-spacing属性で指定します．
以下の仕様を参照してみてください．
https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#letter-spacing

例えば次のように指定します．
<fo:block letter-spacing="1mm">

> 文字字間を一定の（Blockなどの）幅に併せて、広げる／狭めるをする方法

これは、文字揃えでしょうか．
text-align属性で"justify"を指定することで、インライン方向の均等揃えができます．
以下の仕様を参照してみてください．

https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#text-align

なお、この文字揃えの属性で文字間の指定は出来ません．